# defnk is missing in Clojure 1.5.1

Tags: clojure

I am learning Clojure and using Clojure 1.5.1. It seems Clojure 1.5.1 no longer has the defnk macro. So, what is the equivalent for defnk in Clojure 1.5.1 ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`defnk` once resided in clojure-contrib, but didn't make the jump into a new package when clojure-contrib was splitted up into multiple packages.

Instead of `defnk` you could use `:keys`/`:or` yourself to create default values for your function arguments, so

```
(defnk f [:b 43] (inc b))
```

becomes

```
(defn f [& {:keys [b] :or {b 1}}] (inc b))
```

---

If you don't like it this way, nothing stops you from taking the [source](https://github.com/richhickey/clojure-contrib/blob/master/src/main/clojure/clojure/contrib/def.clj) of `defnk` and use it yourself.